# How can I disable touchpad functionality of the mouse keys of my Fujitsu Lifebook E744?

Tags: mouse, touchpad

My Fujitsu E744 notebook has an integrated touchpad, i.e. the mouse keys are also part of the touchpad and sensitive to finger swipes translating into cursor movements. This is extremely annoying for me. Therefore my question: How can I deactivate the touchpad functionality of the mouse button area without disabling the complete touchpad?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Download/Index.asp
Use the serial number to find apptopriate drivers
I used DeskUpdate: Automatic driver update
and now the OS detects my USB mouse and turns the track pad off!

Comment: The user asks that the touchpad still function as the mouse but that mouse button functions be disabled. He does not want the touchpad disabled entirely.